# Docker, sbt - cannot install sbt with centos docker image

Tags: docker, centos, sbt, dockerfile

I would like to have sbt in my `docker` image. I created a `Dockerfile` base on `centos:centos8` image:

```
FROM centos:centos8
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.13.1
ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.18

RUN  yum install -y epel-release
RUN  yum update -y && yum install -y wget

RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/sbt-launch.jar http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/$SBT_VERSION/sbt-launch.jar

WORKDIR /root
EXPOSE 8080

RUN sbt compile
CMD sbt run
```

And also I need to have `sbt` installed here, but when I ran this script I got an error:

```
Step 10/11 : RUN sbt compile
 ---> Running in 0aadcd774ba0
/bin/sh: sbt: command not found
```

I cannot understand why `sbt` could not been found. Is it a good way to achieve what I need or I should try other one? But I need to do it with `centos`

**EDIT:**

Finally it works after help from answer below. Working script looks like:

```
FROM centos:centos8
ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.17

RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk && \
    yum install -y epel-release && \
    yum update -y && yum install -y wget && \
    wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.rpm && \
    yum install -y sbt-$SBT_VERSION.rpm

WORKDIR /root
EXPOSE 8080

RUN sbt compile
CMD sbt run
```

Comment: I don’t think anything in the Dockerfile creates an executable file named `sbt` in the system path.  Just downloading a jar file won’t do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to install `sbt` inside your `Dockerfile`. Here is an example:

```
FROM centos:centos8
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.13.1
ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.17

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y wget

# INSTALL JAVA
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk

# INSTALL SBT
RUN wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.rpm
RUN yum install -y sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.rpm

RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/sbt-launch.jar http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/$SBT_VERSION/sbt-launch.jar

WORKDIR /root
EXPOSE 8080

RUN sbt compile
CMD sbt run
```

**Note: I did not see the version you had in your env variable (0.13.18) so I changed it to 0.13.17.**

Comment: Did it work for you? I got `The command '/bin/sh -c yum install sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: Forgot the `-y`. I'll update the line. I actually didn't test it but the problem that you have is that `sbt` doesn't exist inside your image.

Comment: It's better now, but I got `Step 10/11 : RUN sbt compile
 ---> Running in 66ec059d2144
/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 262: java: command not found
Copying runtime jar.
mkdir: cannot create directory '': No such file or directory
/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 74: java: command not found
/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 74: java: command not found` so probably I need to install `java` too

Comment: Yeah I got curiuos and ran it as well. So same answer, you need to install all the dependencies of your app. You could probably use `RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk`

Comment: Finally it works. Thank you. I add solution to first post

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where bintray.com was returning 403 randomly. I'm assuming it might be some kind of traffic throttle. Added the rpm file locally.

```
COPY sbt-0.13.18.rpm /
RUN yum install -y sbt-0.13.18.rpm
```